# Що означає слово "кіряти"?

Tags: значення-слів, дієслова

У творі Ю. Винничука "Весняні ігри в осінніх садах" знаходжу таке речення:

> Ти збираєшся далі **кіряти**?

Зветаюся у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/kirjaty), аби з’ясувати семантику слова, однак інформації не знайшла.

Comment: ВІдповіль на це запитання легко знайти Google-пошуком.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Це сленг:

[КИРЯТИ](http://slovopedia.org.ua/57/53402/374719.html) , КІРЯТИ 
(-яю, -яєш) недок., (що); мол., крим. Пити спиртні напої; пиячити.